# maven not using snapshot dependency from local .m2 folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have two services. Both are spring boot applications.
Service 1
Below is the groupId and Artifact Id of Service 1

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>service-1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Inside this i have some classes

```
--com
    |
    example
    | 
    util
    |
    UtilClass.java
```

Now, I did a clean deploy. and i can see the jar in my .m2 folder

2. Service 2

I have another spring boot application with the below groupId and artifactId

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>service-2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Here i have a package structure

```
--com
    |
    example
    | 
    service
    |
    ServiceClass.java
```

I have added Service 1 as a dependency on my pom.xml of service 2. When i try to import my UtilClass from service 1, into Service 2. It is giving me an error although i can see that Service 1 in maven dependencies.

```
import com.example.util.UtilClass;
```

It is not able to find the package util.
What is the best way to use a dependency which is local m2 folder which is a snapshot version

I am using Intellij and spring boot 3.0.3 with Java 17.

Thanks in Advance.